# How can I stop VS Code from automatically terminating the selenium browser instance in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I have following python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html")
```

When I execute this script in the standard python IDE it properly works and my browser instance stays open after the code is finished. For VS Code for some reason it automatically closes the browser instance. However can I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a weird behaviour of the VS Code Python extension. I had the same problem with just pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>. Selecting "Run Python File in Terminal" from the right-click menu solved the problem for me as it doesn't execute the file with any of the clutter, that the standard operation attaches.

Comment: what is the  "clutter"?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I found, that VS Code also had `c:\Users\<USER>\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.4.12954\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 57003` in the command it pasted in the terminal. Clutter is maybe a bit too harsh of a word, but I didn't get what this does and not using it seemed to get rid of the problem. I would be thankful to know what the purpose of this line is

Comment: The menu option that worked for me was "Run Current File in Interactive Window"